# Trying to make a script check apache status

Tags: bash

So here is my bash script.

```
APACHECHECK="$which telnet localhost 80"

echo -e "\n Checking APACHE\n"

$($APACHECHECK)

#if [[ $($APACHECHECK) == *Connected* ]]; then
#
#       echo -e "Apache is running on port 80 :)"
#               else
#                       echo -e "\n Apache is down!"
#               fi
#
```

Ignore the comments. The script runs `telnet localhost 80`. If it returns "Connected" then it reports that apache is running.

The problem is the script isn't fully running. Here is output of my script:

```
root@vr6 [~]# ./megatool 

 Checking APACHE

telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
```

Here is me running telnet localhost 80

```
root@vr6 [~]# telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Also I would like to suppress output and just have my script report the echo of apache is running or its not like my if then statement.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `apachectl`? It comes with apache and lets you do this:

```
apachectl status
```

Answer (score 2):

To help with the telnet solution:

```
if telnet localhost 80 </dev/null 2>&1 | grep -q Connected; then
  echo "Connected"
else
  echo "no connection"
fi
```